# If $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},........,a_{n}$ are $n$ distinct odd natural numbers, Then Sum of its Reciprocal is Less than

Tags: number-theory

> If $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},........,a_{n}$ are $n$ distinct odd natural numbers not divisible by any prime
>
> number $>5\;,$Then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a_{1}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}}+.......+\frac{1}{a_{n}}$ is less then

$\bf{Options::}\;\; $ $\displaystyle (a)\;\; \frac{15}{8}\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;\; \frac{8}{15}\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\;\; \frac{7}{4}\;\;\;\;\;\; (d)\;\; \frac{4}{7}\;\;\;\;\;\; $

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ Let $\displaystyle a_{1} = 2k_{1}+1\;,a_{2}=2k_{2}+1\;,a_{3}=2k_{3}+1\;,...........a_{n}=2k_{n}+1$

And Here $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}.......,a_{n}$ are Maximum such that its product is Less.

But I did not Understand it How can I found such odd no. which are not divisible by Prime no. $>5$

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: Did you try AM-HM inequality?The form looks similar to the general form of the AM-HM inequality...

Comment: Option $(a)$; if the sum is less than any of the other values, it is certainly less than $\tfrac{15}{8}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  odd numbers which are not divisible by a prime greater than $5$ are of the form $3^b5^c$  You can get the sum of the reciprocals of these from the product of two geometric series.

Comment: Actually only two series as they are odd.

Comment: @cr001:  Thanks.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i} <\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\:\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 3^{-j}\:5^{-k}=$$ $$=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}3^{-j}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}5^{-k}\right)=$$ $$=\frac {1}{1-1/3}\cdot\frac {1}{1-1/5}=\frac{15}{8}.$$